# jinja template nested loop only giving last loop value as output in ansible playbook

Tags: azure, templates, ansible, jinja2

My playbook task is to fetch all resource groups then list all the vms under each resource group and for each vm find the tags associated with it. I am getting correct output when running my playbook. But I am not able to save it correctly using jinja template. Here, is the template I am using:

```
{
{% for rg in group_list %}
"resource_group": "{{ rg }}",
{% for vm in vm_list %}
"vmId": "{{ vm }}",
{% if vmTag_json|length > 0 %}
{% for key, value in vmTag_json.items() %}
"Key": "{{ key }}",
"Value": "{{ value }}"
{% if not loop.last %},{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{% else %}
"tags": "NA"
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
}
```

And the output I am getting is:

```
{
"resource_group": "RG1",
"vmId": "VM-01",
"Key": "Test",
"Value": "win"
"vmId": "VM-02",
"Key": "Test",
"Value": "win"
}
```

Tags value is coming same for every machine which is the last value in the loop. Also a "," should come after "Value": "win" if the loop is not ended, it is also not coming and if I put it then it also comes after the last value.

Comment: It sure does look like you're trying to recreate [`| to_json`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.10/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#formatting-data-yaml-and-json) by hand, which is the road to ruin

Comment: So, what should be the best way to do it? I need this json file to save this data in influx db.